# Replace multiple String characters and quotes in a file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace an entry in the Google chrome local state file.
Replace

`"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":[],"last_redirect_origin":""`

with

`"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":["same-site-by-default-cookies@2"],"last_redirect_origin":""`

I am using

`(Get-content "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\local state") -replace '"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":[],"last_redirect_origin":"', '"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":["same-site-by-default-cookies@2"],"last_redirect_origin":""'`

I am getting

`The regular expression pattern "browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":[],"last_redirect_origin":" is not valid. At line:1 char:1`

Comment: The data sure looks like JSON. Why not use Json -aware cmdlets to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do ordinary replace like C#'s `string.Replace()`, but in posh `-replace` operates on regexes and seems like your literal unfortunately happens to be invalid regex expression. Try with `.Replace()`, this way:

```
(Get-content "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\local state").Replace( `
'"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":[],"last_redirect_origin":"', `
'"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":["same-site-by-default-cookies@2"],"last_redirect_origin":""')
```

Note that I added ` at the end of each line, that's just for better formatting.

Comment: I no longer get the error but no replace happens.